# How can I recognize keys from a second keyboard?

Tags: multilingual

I bought a second keyboard, USB with 20 programmable keys.  I'm using Windows. 
The programming utility foresees using it for gaming, for macros, or as a number keypad, but I need it for another script - I don't want to duplicate keys I already have on my normal keyboard.

I notice that normal keycodes for the function keys F1-F12 are 112-123, but this utility offers me function keys F1-F20, presumably with codes 112-131.  For my 20 extra keys, I'd like to use 124-143, as if they were F13-F32: I want to be able to recognize keys from the second keypad unambiguously.  NumLock is 144, but there doesn't seem to be any codes in my range.

But is there a correct or better way to do this?  I can't be the first person to want to add more keys to a keyboard.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I'm using Windows.